# screen command cannot find java executable

Tags: rhel, gnu-screen, java

I'm trying to execute `java` from `screen`:

```
screen -S my-java-app -d -m 'java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m my-java-app.jar'
```

but seems that screen does not know the `java` command. Running `java` without `screen` works just fine.

```
java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m my-java-app.jar
```

I'm using RHEL5.

Comment: Why do you think that screen doesn't know `java` command? What are the symptoms?

Comment: How did you find out to screen doesn't know java command?

Comment: if I run it without "-d" I see on the top of screen that note

Comment: it was working fine 1 month ago, but someone did something on server, and now its not :(

Comment: What's the output of `which java` when ran from outside of `screen` ?

Comment: Try: `screen -S my-java-app -d -m 'type -f java'`

Comment: Why do you think that “screen does not know the java command”? Did you get an error message? If so, copy-paste it into your question. If you run `screen -S test-sleep -d -m sleep 999999`, do you see the `sleep` process in `ps -e | grep sleep`?

Comment: which worked only for non-root. in root I had alias to java, which obviously didn't worked for screen. I solved it by answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by:
editing `/etc/bashrc`

`# JAVA
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/java-i386-60/jre/
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`